# String replace in specific positioned in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, c#-4.0

I have a string `Classic-T50 (Black+Grey)`
when i send to by query string it will show in next page

```
Classic-T50 (Black Grey)
```

so i want to add  + in space in this string only within bracket() only portion.

```
Classic-T50 (Black+Grey).
```

I have tried `string.Replace(" ","+")`.But it produce

```
Classic-T50+(Black+Grey).
```

But i want string `Classic-T50 (Black+Grey).`

Help me please.

Comment: You should url encode your string.

Comment: the query string in Gridview 
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="serve"
       AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ModelName" SortExpression="ModelName">
                <ItemTemplate>       
                   <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Ovee Sir/ModelWiseReport_Issues.aspx?Model="+Eval("ModelName") %>' Text='<%# Eval("ModelName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

now how can i encode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` and convert back to `string`. StringBuilder's differ from strings in that they're mutable and noninterned. It stores data in an array, and so you can replace characters like you would in an array:

```
void Main()
{
    var input = "Classic-T50 (Black Grey)";
    StringBuilder inputsb = new StringBuilder(input);
    var openParens = input.IndexOf('(');
    var closeParens = input.IndexOf(')');
    var count = closeParens - openParens;
    //Console.WriteLine(input);
    //inputsb[18] = '+';
    inputsb.Replace(' ', '+', openParens, count);
    Console.WriteLine(inputsb.ToString());
}
```

See [StringBuilder.Replace Method (Char, Char, Int32, Int32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149403(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for replacing all spaces inside brackets:

```
var pattern = @"\s(?![^)]*\()";
var data = "Classic-T50 (Black Grey)";
var replacement = "+";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var transformedData = regex.Replace(data, replacement); // Classic-T50 (Black+Grey)
```

This approach will work for any input string. E.g., the string `Caption ( A B C D )` will transform to `Caption (+A+B+C+D+)`.

Additional links:

- Regex explanation: https://regex101.com/r/aN8fV2/1
- [MSDN: Regex.Replace Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx)

Comment: Dude.. You are awsome !!

Answer (score 2):

What is the format of the strings that you want to modify? Will this code work?

```
void Main()
{
    var str = "Classic-T50 (Black Grey)";

    Console.WriteLine(FormatWithPlus(str));
}

public string FormatWithPlus(string str){
    var str1 = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('('));
    var str2 = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('('));

    return str1 + str2.Replace(' ', '+');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
String.Replace("k ","k+")
```

Comment: seems that your requirement was refined to replace all spaces within parentheses with plus signs. you could use the string builder example i have below; i'll modified for the new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can UrlEncode it to preserve the special character:

```
Server.UrlEncode(mystring)
```

Or replace + sign with "%252b" and then encode it:

```
string myTitle = mystring.Trim().Replace("+", "%252b"); 
Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx?title=" + Server.UrlEncode(myTitle));
```

Remember to decode it once you try to retrieve it :

```
Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["title"]);
```

Comment: In case of `"%252b` you will get `%2b`. You don't need to encode escape character.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string abc = "Classic-T50 (Black Grey)";
            var a = abc.Replace("k ", "k+");
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```